# How do I set the Start Action (external program) used by csproj file from powershell

Tags: powershell, nuget, envdte

I'm writing a nuget install script in powershell and I want to set the 'Start Action' for the project file (*.csproj). I have access to the Project interface from EnvDTE vai the variable $project.

I know setting the 'Start Action' manually creates a local *.user file in the file system, is there anyway I can do this programmatically from a powershell script via EnvDTE?

Answer (score 4):

This is how I achieved it:

```
param($installPath, $toolsPath, $package, $project)

function HasStartAction ($item)
{
    foreach ($property in $item.Properties)
    {
       if ($property.Name -eq "StartAction")
       {
           return $true
       }            
    } 

    return $false
}

function ModifyConfigurations
{
    $configurationManager = $project.ConfigurationManager

    foreach ($name in $configurationManager.ConfigurationRowNames)
    {
        $projectConfigurations = $configurationManager.ConfigurationRow($name)

        foreach ($projectConfiguration in $projectConfigurations)
        {                

            if (HasStartAction $projectConfiguration)
            {
                $newStartAction = 1
                $newStartProgram = $fullPath + "bin\" + $name + "\Shell\XXXX.exe"
                $newWorkingDirectory = $fullPath + "bin\" + $name + "\Shell\"

                write-host "StartAction - " $newStartAction
                write-host "StartProgram - " $newStartProgram
                write-host "WorkingDirectory - " $newWorkingDirectory

                $projectConfiguration.Properties.Item("StartAction").Value = $newStartAction
                $projectConfiguration.Properties.Item("StartProgram").Value = $newStartProgram
                $projectConfiguration.Properties.Item("StartWorkingDirectory").Value = $newWorkingDirectory
            }
        }
    }

    $project.Save
}

write-host "Modifying Configurations..."
ModifyConfigurations
```

Comment: In VS2015, I had to add a [String] in front of the $newStartProgram assignment to make it work successfully. But, other than that, worked like a charm.